# How to add "sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator.StatusIndicator" to page?

Tags: sapui5

What I am trying to do is add one Status Indicator on my page. When I run the app, I am not getting any error on the console, but status indicator isn't appear on my page.

Here is the xml code of my page,

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:statusindicator="sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator"
  controllerName="EarthMonitoring.controller.DetailPage"
>
  <Page showHeader="false">
    <statusindicator:StatusIndicator id="statusIndicator2" width="300px" height="300px" value="90" />
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Here is the capture of the result:

[image: the image should appear on the detail page]

The image should appear on the detail page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is because you failed to specify the [`ShapeGroup`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator.ShapeGroup) and the [`PropertyTreshold`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator.PropertyThreshold).

See this example:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<si:StatusIndicator xmlns:si="sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator" id="idIndicator" value="40">
  <si:ShapeGroup>
    <si:Rectangle x="0" y="0" width="50" height="100" strokeWidth="1" fillingType="Linear"/>
  </si:ShapeGroup>
  <si:propertyThresholds>
    <si:PropertyThreshold fillColor="Critical" toValue="60"/>
    <si:PropertyThreshold fillColor="Error" toValue="30"/>
    <si:PropertyThreshold fillColor="Good" toValue="100"/>
  </si:propertyThresholds>
</si:StatusIndicator>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i didn't know if we wanted to add some statusindicator on the view, we should init the shapegroup and propertyThreshold.